# Cannot npm install --save electron because group policy prevent CMD execution in %appdata% folder

Tags: node.js, windows, npm, electron, appdata

## Issue

Our group-policies does not allow to execute `cmd` files from the windows `%appdata%` folder. When I try to install `electron` this error happens:

```
npm install --save electron

npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path C:\data\dev\dy\we\quick-start\node_modules\electron
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c C:\Users\X\AppData\Local\Temp\postinstall-a836babe.cmd
npm ERR! Blocked by group policy. Please contact your system administrator (translated).
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\X\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-09-06T09_22_56_569Z-debug-0.log
```

## Tried solution

Overrule the installation path by adding

```
prefix = 'C:\data\dev\npm-global'
```

into `C:\Users\X\.npmrc` file, but the error persits.

## Question

Is there any possibility, to change the usage of `%appdata%` to a custom folder like `C:\data\dev\npm-global` ?

Since there is always a dynamic `electron-a86xxxx.cmd` file downloaded it is not possible to whitelist a specific file for the `%appdata%` folder.

## Used Versions

Node: v16.17.0

NPM: 8.15.0

## EDIT 1

`npm get prefix` outputs this `C:\data\dev\npm-global`

## EDIT 2

`npm config list` outputs this `prefix = "C:\\Users\\X\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm" ; overridden by user`

## EDIT 3

Found another `.npmrc` config file in `C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm` and updated it as well.

## EDIT 4

Executing `npm install -g electron` results in the same error. NPM always wants to run a CMD file from the %appdata% folder.

## EDIT 5

It seems like the command `npm install -g electron` did work and does put the files into the `C:\data\dev\npm-global` folder. But `electron` still wants to execute the cmd file from the appdata folder.

## EDIT 6

The issue seems to be with the `postinstall-xxxxxxx.cmd` which seems to be `electron` specific. I already installed NodeJS into `C:\data\dev\NodeJS` but the `electron` installation still wants to execute a cmd from the appfolder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into the same problem you're having with **npm 8.15.0**, albeit with a different package. I upgraded to the latest non-LTS release, which at the time of this writing is **node 18.10.0** and **npm 8.19.2**, and the issue went away.

I do have the following set in `.npmrc`. I don't know if they made a difference (it still failed with **npm 8.15.0**), as I haven't tried without them there. I do know npm states it ignores the **tmp** config value, so it may not be needed.

```
tmp=C:\some\safe\dir\npm
cache=C:\some\safe\dir\npm-cache
```